# Is it possible to create an Anchor that doesn't load a page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create an anchor that does not load a page, but rather just triggers a client-side script.

My problem is the anchor I create will always reload the current page when clicked (though, yes, it does first perform the ClientHandler code via addClickHandler). This is how I'm creating my anchor:

```
app.createAnchor(text, '').setTarget('_self');
```

This generates html with a blank 'href'. I've also tried with a href of '#' but that ends up in html with a href like 'http://www.google.com/url?q=%23&sa=N&usd=2&usg=AFQjCNGs0Cz4Vz7tdafpLWloZGOjmdJv4Q' and it leads to a redirect loop. (I thought the Hyperlink widget (and InlineHyperlink) might do what I want but they are not only deprecated, they've actually been removed now too.)

I just wondered if it could be done with Anchors in the UiService - I can't find a way. (I've posted this as answered due to my own workarounds, but I'd be interested to hear from anyone who has a solution using Anchor widgets)

Answer (score 1):

An acceptable workaround might be to create a Label instead of an Anchor, and then styling it so that you get the 'pointer' hand mouse icon rather than the standard arrow cursor.

```
app.createLabel(text).setStyleAttributes({cursor: 'pointer'});
```

A different workaround is to code it with the HtmlService instead, using simple Javascript (JQuery works nicely too). Set href to '#' and add an onclick handler.